# R Shiny htmloutput inline with imageoutput

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I have a shiny app which is displaying a variable (say var1) in a given formatting using htmloutput. Based on output of var1, an image, which is a logo of var1 is to be changed which I'm displaying through imageOutput. I'm displaying all this under absolutePanel.

But the image is coming **below** the line of text given by htmlOutput. Anyway I can have them in the same line?

Can htmlOutput include images in itself? If so, how?

EDIT: From what I've found, I need to use the span() function but I don't know how to use it for my purpose

So this is what it looks like right now:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I would like it to look like this:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I know very little html to figure out how to fix this. If I inspect element and anyone out there who wants to view the html, here you go: [![enter image description here][3]][3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learned enough CSS to fix this.

Call the HTML function inside ui.R and changed the display of the party name htmlOutput to inline-block so that it allows other elements to come in the same line like so:

```
tags$head(tags$style(
HTML('
      #winner {
                  display:inline-block;
      }
    ')
))
```